# cAdvisor does not show all container's uptime (Prometheus+cAdvisor+Grafana)

Tags: linux, docker, grafana, prometheus, cadvisor

**Environment:**

- Linux (Redhat7)
- Deployed docker (cAdvisor, Prometheus, Grafana)
- cAdvisor collect the metrics > Pass to Prometheus > Display with Grafana
- Apache reverse proxy is in the environment (Therefore no direct connection with specific ports)

**Issue:**

- cAdvisor does not show all container's uptime
- Grafana does not show Prometheus and Grafana container's uptime
- Only displays cAdvisor container's uptime

**What I have (Issue):**
[image]
[image]

**What I want to have:**
[image]

**Setting in Prometheus:**
[image]
[image]

**Command to run cAdvisor:**

sudo docker run --volume=/:/rootfs:ro --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro --volume=/dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro --publish=8080:8080 --name=cadvisor  --detach=true --privileged=true --volume=/cgroup:/cgroup:ro --network=docker8443 --ip=172.28.5.201 google/cadvisor:latest

**Questions:**

- Is something missing in Prometheus target to show all container's uptime?
- Is something missing in cAdvisor setup?
- Is query for the graph incorrect? (I have tried following, but it shows "No data point")
  [image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is about cadvisor. 
You can try check the cadvisor metrics endpoint: http://172.28.5.201:8080/metrics 
to make sure the cadvisor return the metrics samples:

example:

```
# HELP container_start_time_seconds Start time of the container since unix epoch in seconds.
# TYPE container_start_time_seconds gauge
container_start_time_seconds{id="/",image="",name=""} 1.525939343e+09
container_start_time_seconds{id="/docker",image="",name=""} 1.526006565e+09
container_start_time_seconds{id="/docker/d4b87911bd0842ee1d6969e6a05aa3d36a48a801184faf14e1b23169e056da92",image="busybox",name="trusting_bassi"}
```

Comment: Thank you Yunlong, I have tested and confirmed the metrics are working, but the content of each container is still missing.

Comment: I just test in my local. The command start cadvisor is missing volume /sys.
you can add try add --volume=/sys:/sys:ro in your command and test again.

The Prometheus and PromQL in Grafana looks ok.

Comment: Thank you Yunlong, that was the issue, --volume=/sys:/sys:ro, did the job, much appreciated for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

On top of Yunlong's answer: add `--volume=/sys:/sys:ro`
You will also need to run following under shell:

```
$ mount -o remount,rw '/sys/fs/cgroup'

$ ln -s /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct,cpu
```

Otherwise your cAdvisor crashes immediately after container is up.